# Get dominant color from image in React JS

Tags: reactjs, colors

I'm trying to get the dominant colors from a loaded image using this [repo](https://github.com/nitin42/react-color-extractor/blob/master/examples/WithSrc.js).

Here's my try:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ColorExtractor } from 'react-color-extractor';

const App = () => {

    const [colors, setColors] = useState([]);
    const getColors = color => {
        setColors([...colors, ...color])
    }

    const ColorGet = (file) => {
        //file.preview = blob
        return <>
            <ColorExtractor src={file.preview} getColors={getColors} />
            {console.log('colors: ', colors)}
        </>
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
        ColorGet(values.upl_Picture[0]);
        //...
    }

    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete="off" className="form">
        {/* ... */}
    </form>
}

export default App;
```

Why inside `ColorGet` the output for `colors` is an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example for how to extract the dominant colors from an image using [react-color-extractor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-color-extractor).

```
import { useState } from "react";
import exampleImage from './example.png';
import { ColorExtractor } from 'react-color-extractor';

function GetColorExample() {
    const [imgColors, setImgColors] = useState();

    return (
        <div>
            <ColorExtractor getColors={colors => setImgColors(colors)}>
                <img src={exampleImage}/>
            </ColorExtractor>
        </div>
    )
}

export default GetColorExample;
```